# .NET C++ writing UI from other thread

Tags: .net, c++

In .Net C++, I want to write the serial input to a textBox on the UI.  But of course the serial input is on another thread.  I am guessing that I need to pass in a delegate to the serial thread when I create it to run the function below called updateTextBoxes.  I tried making a delegate as below but I am stuck at what I need to put in the argument list when the delegate is created.  This is all in my Form1 class.

```
       public delegate void MyDel();

        void updateTextBoxes()
        {
           this->local_long_textBox->Text = "Test!!!!!!!"
        }



private: void startUp()
    {
       MyDel^ DelInst;
       DelInst = gcnew MyDel( ??? what goes in here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would pass the arguments that are required for the constructor

Comment: Oh I get it, I pass in the this pointer for the instance and Form1::testFunc for the second argument.  Great thanks!

Comment: So I can now create the delegate and build it, but how do I use it.  How does one pass in the delegate to a class I invoke.  Whatever I try gets compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` on the text box passing a delegate that sets the Text property.

`Invoke` will execute the delegate on the thread associated with the text box. `BeginInvoke` does the same but asynchronously.